# <body> font size doesn't affect <h> tags

Tags: html, css, sass, font-size

I'm trying to **double my font size on every page** of my HTML project. I did this:

```
body{
  font-size:200% !important;
}
```

on the main css file which is included in every single page, and the result was good on every tag **except** `<h1>` to `<h6>` . They remained as the way they were before. I tried the same trick for these tags,

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
  font-size:200% !important;
}
```

which resulted in extra large font for these tags.
In my inspect element window, I can see that these tags had been over written before I did this to them, and their `font-size` was changed. my  `font-size:200% !important`removed their previous `font-size`  and now they have their standard font-size *2.

**I need to keep that modified font-size for `<h1>` to `<h6>`, and just make it double**. Doing it by changing font-size for every single one of them would be inefficient. Is there anyway to force them to obey `<body>` font-size rule?

**Edit:** I also realized there are some other classes which haven't been affected by my rule to body tag. As an instance, divs with ionic form-message class.
Now this is getting weird. :|

Comment: Maybe by putting the text that you want to change in a different <div> and give it a class an call that class in your css file?

Comment: html file is protected; in chrome inspect element tool, I tried adding "font-size:200% !important" to the outer div. result was the same as what I mentioned above.

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/zkL08a14/

Comment: @Svenmarim also, I'm talking about a hundred page web-app, unfortunately I can't change every one of them manually. I t would be...tedious. :D

Comment: @Mr.Alien as I mentioned, my <h1> to <h2> DOES GET BIGGER. The problem is, for example, h1 is defined to have font-size: 25px. When font-size:200% !important is assigned to it, it goes back to it's default font-size, THEN  gets double. I need it to double that "25px".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome at least, the font size for `h1` etc. is defined as `2em`. Therefore, it will be a multiple of whatever font size is in effect on an ancestor, including the body.

```html
<div style="font-size: 200%; ">
  <h1>This is h1.</h1>
  <h2>This is h2.</h2>
  <p>This is p.</p>
</div>
```

`2em` for `h1` is the suggested, recommended default setting, [as per the W3C](https://hell.meiert.org/core/css/css-2.2.css), so I would expect most if not all browsers to follow it.

If this doesn't work for some reason, you could try defining the size of `h1` etc. using `rem`, which refers to the font size on the `html` element, but you would have to set them individually.

> on the main css file which is included in every single page, and the result was good on every tag except `<h1>` to `<h6>`.

What browser was that? Some browsers might define the font size for `h1` etc. in the user agent stylesheet not using `em`, but that would surprise me.

Comment: I'm editing an Android app UI. I'm using chrome://inspect to monitor the changes I apply to it.

Comment: Also, I tried defining h1 to h6 font-size with rem, but they didn't change. I used it on my "input" fields which I just realized haven't changed by my rule to body tag, and they got so big that an overflow occurred. I was expecting something like 20px, and I got 48px.

Comment: `rem` is based on the font size of the **`html`** element, so if you're going to use `rem`, make sure to put your `font-size: 200%` on the `html` element.

Comment: One question. Basically, if I use  font-size: 200% on my <html> and set everyone else's font property to 1rem, that would double everyone's font size?

Comment: this one somehow solved the issue. I added 1em to each <h> tag and they followed the rule. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> From the MDN: these elements have a rank given by the number in their name

That means you cannot use always 200% for each element, but a different value like in:

```css
h1 { font-size: 400%;}  /* The chrome def value: 2em */
h2 { font-size: 300%;}  /* The chrome def value: 1.5em */
h3 { font-size: 234%;}  /* The chrome def value: 1.17em */
h4 { font-size: 200%;}  /* The chrome def value: 1em */
h5 { font-size: 166%;}  /* The chrome def value: 0.83em */
h6 { font-size: 134%;}  /* The chrome def value: 0.67em */
```

```html
<h1>h1</h1>
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
<h4>h4</h4>
<h5>h5</h5>
<h6>h6</h6>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but if they have a default value, I think by using font-size:200% on all of them I would get 4 em,3 em,2.34 em,2 em,1.66 em and 1.34 em. I can't see why I should use different percentage for each one.

Comment: @SarahAmini If you see the h4 tag you see 1 while h1 is 2. This means: h1 is the double of h4. And because h4 has the default font size, and because h1,h2... elements must have different size according to a rank.....you have different percentage.

Comment: I got it. So finally you suggest that I have to apply changes to each tag individually?

Comment: @SarahAmini Yes, you need to respect the ratio among them. Right for instance, if h4 is 1em and h1 is 2em: this means h1 is the double of h4.... so if you set h4 to 200% this implies h1 must be set to 400%. I hope this will help you. Let me know